# Use of BoringLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, canvas, android-custom-view, drawtext

I're read on the Android documentation the next:

> You should not need to use this class directly unless you are
>   implementing your own widget or custom display object, in which case
>   **you are encouraged to use a Layout instead of calling Canvas.drawText()** directly.

I've always used `Canvas.drawText()` each time I wrote a custom widget.

I'm doing this wrong?

If I want (for instance) draw a circle with a number in the middle of it, should I use `BoringLayout`?

Comment: What's `BoringLayout`?

Comment: @Funkystein http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/BoringLayout.html